# Jest mock factory not working for class mock

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm trying to mock an service class to test an React component. But the module factory from jest.mock is not working.

Search component:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import SearchService from "../../services/SearchService";

export default function Search() {
  const [searchResults, setSearchResults] = useState([]);

  function doSearch() {
    const service = new SearchService();
    service.search().then(setSearchResults);
  }

  return (
    <div className="component-container">
      <div>
        <button onClick={doSearch}>search</button>
      </div>
      {searchResults.map((result) => (
        <div key={result}>{result}</div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

SearchService:

```
export default class SearchService {
  search = function () {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      setTimeout(
        () => resolve(["result 1", "result 2", "result 3", "result 4"]),
        1000
      );
    });
  };
}
```

Test file:

```
import React from "react";
import { screen, render } from "@testing-library/react";
import userEvent from "@testing-library/user-event";
import { act } from "react-dom/test-utils";
import Search from "../features/search/Search";

jest.mock("../services/SearchService", () => {
  return jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
    return { search: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(["mock result"]) };
  });
});

test("Search", async () => {
  render(<Search />);
  const button = screen.getByRole("button");
  expect(button).toBeDefined();
  act(() => {
    userEvent.click(button);
  });
  await screen.findByText("mock result");
});
```

This is the same structure as the [Jest documentation example](https://jestjs.io/docs/es6-class-mocks#calling-jestmock-with-the-module-factory-parameter). In the code above I'm passing the mock implementation through the module factory parameter of the jest.mock.
But it does not work. When I log the new SerchService() I get "mockConstructor {}" and when I run the test it throws the error "service.search is not a function".

When I change my test file to...

```
import React from "react";
import { screen, render } from "@testing-library/react";
import userEvent from "@testing-library/user-event";
import { act } from "react-dom/test-utils";
import Search from "../features/search/Search";
import SearchService from "../services/SearchService";

jest.mock("../services/SearchService");

test("Search", async () => {
  SearchService.mockImplementation(() => {
    return { search: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(["mock result"]) };
  });
  render(<Search />);
  const button = screen.getByRole("button");
  expect(button).toBeDefined();
  act(() => {
    userEvent.click(button);
  });
  await screen.findByText("mock result");
});
```

It works...
I kinda can understand why it works in the second way, it is like using jest.spyOn I guess. What I cant understand is why it doesnt work with the first approach.

What I'm doing wrong? How can I mock a module implementation with jest.mock without calling .mockImplementation inside each test?

Comment: Why is the service a class to begin with? Just export a function, there's no state. In general things shouldn't `new` up their collaborators because then they become very coupled.

Comment: Hi @jonrsharpe, this is not a real project, I'm trying to learn about unit test so I created this fake service as a class to try to mock a class.

Answer (score -1):

I found that there is a problem with the documentation and that the factory needs to return an function() (not an arrow function), so I changed the mock to the following and it works:

```
jest.mock("../services/SearchService.js", () => {
  return function () {
    return { search: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(["mock result"]) };
  };
});
```

Found on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47402005/jest-mock-how-to-mock-es6-class-default-import-using-factory-parameter).

Comment: You didn't return an arrow in the OP, you returned Jest spy. There shouldn't be a difference between `return jest.fn().mockImplementation(` and what you posted, unless you reset mocks somewhere (and you shouldn't do this).

Comment: @EstusFlask, are you saying that the OP should have worked? When you say that "I should do this" are you talking about returning a function() or reseting the mocks? I really don't know the right way to do it, I followed the docs example and it didn't work.

Comment: I cannot say if it's 100% workable, but the code in the answer isn't more correct than the code in the question. I mean the latter, double check there are no `*reset*` things in tests and Jest config. But by returning a function you prevent yourself from using Jest spies, which are useful.