# Mocking screen that uses dependency yields 'is not a constructor' in Jest

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs

I'm using jose's SignJWT in one of my components but it always results to 'jose.SignJWT' is not a constructor. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong lol

Here's how I tried to mock it

```
jest.mock('jose', () => {
  return {
    decodeJwt: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve({})),
    SignJWT: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
      return {
        setProtectedHeader: jest.fn(),
        sign: jest.fn(),
      };
    }),
  };
});
```

I've also tried the ff:

```
jest.mock('jose', () => ({
  __esModule: true,
  decodeJwt: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve({})),
  SignJWT: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
    return {
      setProtectedHeader: jest.fn(() => this),
      sign: jest.fn(() => {}),
    };
  }),
}));
```

but now it says sign `token.sign is not a function`

Here's the class I'm trying to mock if it helps

```
export declare class SignJWT extends ProduceJWT {
    private _protectedHeader;
    /**
     * Sets the JWS Protected Header on the SignJWT object.
     *
     * @param protectedHeader JWS Protected Header. Must contain an "alg" (JWS Algorithm) property.
     */
    setProtectedHeader(protectedHeader: JWTHeaderParameters): this;
    /**
     * Signs and returns the JWT.
     *
     * @param key Private Key or Secret to sign the JWT with. See
     *   {@link https://github.com/panva/jose/issues/210#jws-alg Algorithm Key Requirements}.
     * @param options JWT Sign options.
     */
    sign(key: KeyLike | Uint8Array, options?: SignOptions): Promise<string>;
}
```

Comment: maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47402005/jest-mock-how-to-mock-es6-class-default-import-using-factory-parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is some issue with the way you are setting up the mock. Try this way to mock the 'SignJWT' class :

```
jest.mock('jose', () => ({
  __esModule: true,
  ...jest.requireActual('jose'), // Use the actual implementation for other exports
  SignJWT: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({
    setProtectedHeader: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
    sign: jest.fn(),
  })),
}));
```

Give this approach a try and see if it resolves the "is not a constructor" issue. If you come across the "token.sign is not a function" problem, double-check that the sign method is mocked correctly, following the provided example.

Comment: Ohhh I guess it was my mocking of setProtectedHeader that was wrong?? Thanks